# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: mongodb, docker, yaml

How can I resolve this issue/error?

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType.

I am not sure why, but I can't grasp the yml world the yml file is here:

```
  1 version: "3.8"
  2 services:
  3 mongodb:
  4   image: mongo
  5   container_name: mongodb
  6   environment:
  7     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=microservice
  8     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=A1d2r3i4a5n!
  9   volumes:
 10     - mongodb-data:/data/db
 11   networks:
 12     - mongodb_network
 13   ports:
 14     - 27017:27017
 15   healthcheck:
 16     test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo 192.168.254.135:27017/test --quiet
 17     interval: 30s
 18     timeout: 10s
 19     retries: 3
 20     restart: unless-stopped
 21 mongo-express:
 22   image: mongo-express
 23   container_name: mongo-express
 24   environment:
 25     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
 26     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
 27     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=microservice
 28     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=A1d2r3i4a5n!
 29     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
 30     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin123
 31   volumes:
 32     - mongodb-data
 33   depends_on:
 34     - mongodb
 35   networks:
 36     - mongodb_network
 37   ports:
 38     - 8081:8081
 39   healthcheck:
 40     test:  wget --quiet --tries=3 --spider http://admin:admin123@192.168.254.135:8081 || exit 1
 41     interval: 30s
 42     timeout: 10s
 43     retries: 3
 44     restart: unless-stopped
 45   volumes:
 46     mongodb-data:
 47       name: mongodb-data
 48     networks:
 49       mongodb_network:
 50       name: mongodb_network
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue comes from you indentation. Check the docker-compose [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) and the YAML syntax.

You definition should look something like this:

```
  1 version: "3.8"
  2 services:
  3   mongodb:
  4     image: mongo
  5     container_name: mongodb
  6     environment:
  7       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=microservice
  8       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=A1d2r3i4a5n!
  9     volumes:
 10       - mongodb-data:/data/db
 11     networks:
 12       - mongodb_network
 13     ports:
 14       - 27017:27017
 15     healthcheck:
 16       test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo 192.168.254.135:27017/test --quiet
 17       interval: 30s
 18       timeout: 10s
 19       retries: 3
 20     restart: unless-stopped
 21   mongo-express:
 22     image: mongo-express
 23     container_name: mongo-express
 24     environment:
 25       - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
 26       - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
 27       - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=microservice
 28       - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=A1d2r3i4a5n!
 29       - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
 30       - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin123
 31     volumes:
 32       - mongodb-data:/data/db
 33     depends_on:
 34       - mongodb
 35     networks:
 36       - mongodb_network
 37     ports:
 38       - 8081:8081
 39     healthcheck:
 40       test:  wget --quiet --tries=3 --spider http://admin:admin123@192.168.254.135:8081 || exit 1
 41       interval: 30s
 42       timeout: 10s
 43       retries: 3
 44     restart: unless-stopped
 45     
 46 volumes:
 47   mongodb-data:
 48
 49 networks:
 50   mongodb_network:
```

Comment: followed it, still getting ```ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network 'name' must be a mapping not a string.``` and after running yamllint ```  40:81     error    line too long (92 > 80 characters)  (line-length)```this error shows up

Comment: now getting ```ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mongo-express.healthcheck value 'restart' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'
services.mongodb.healthcheck value 'restart' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'
```

Comment: yup, `restart` is not part of the `healthcheck` mapping. It should be services.mongo-express.restart. I'll edit the original answer

Comment: also `networks.mongodb-data.name` is not a valid key. I've also edited this in the original answer. And you haven't specified where you're mounting the `mongodb-data` for the `mongo-express` service. I put `/data/db` but maybe you should customize it.